# Split String by XML elements

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

I have the following input string which is from a 10MB text file

`string data = "0x52341\n0x52341<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>0x52341\n0x52341 <element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>0x52341<element2><sub>3</sub‌​‌​></element2> <element2><sub>4</sub></element2>0x4312";`

now I want this string by `element1` and `element2` XML nodes

the result in this case should be

```
output[0] = "<element1 value="3"><sub>1</sub></element1>";
output[1] = "<element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>";
output[2] = "<element2><sub>3</sub></element2>";
output[3] = "<element2><sub>4</sub></element2>";
```

**my efford:**

i have tried Regular Expression but that's very slow in case of that big file and i have also tried

```
string[] output= input.Split(new string[] { "<element1>", "<element2>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

`string.Split()` is circuitous because it throws outofmemory exceptions and the delemiter is being removed at splitting.

**question:**
is there a easy way to parse those xml elements out of my text file?

**update:**
I simplified my file because i couldn't post the whole 10MB file in SO - sometimes there are 0x1234 values between the xml elements sometimes not

Comment: i understand that you using c#, you have lot of stuff to deal with html parsing: selenium, .Net htmlagilitypack, mshtml why didn't use them for that purpose ?

Comment: If you are dealing with XML use an XML parser like Linq-to-XML.

Comment: @juharr - that doesn't work, already tried that appraoch. i don't have one root, i have many roots (`element1` and `element2`)

Comment: @kenny - no the whole file not but the `element1` and `element2` are valid xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can *guarantee* that each `<elementX></elementX>` fragment is a well-formed XML node (so to speak), wrap the entire string in `<elements> ... </elements>` and deal with it using standard .NET approaches, be it `XmlDocument`, Linq to XML or whatever else fits you.

Comment: @Byyo Where and what exactly throws? Having text inbetween tags does not make XML ill-formed.

Comment: @Byyo you can parse the text block by block (4096 characters), and delete these characters.

Comment: `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse()` throws `unexpected xml declaration. the xml declaration must be the first node in the document`

Comment: `XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument(); x.LoadXml(file);` throws exactly the same error - just tested

Comment: @Byyo Paste here whatever there is in `file`, verbatim.

Comment: the file is `string data = "0x52341\n0x52341<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>0x234512 <element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>0x52341<element2><sub>3</sub‌​‌​></element2> <element2><sub>4</sub></element2>0x4312";`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
A faster alternative (as its not using Regex) which is not replacing 0x... fragments within the content of the elements would be the following one:

```
string data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>0x52341<element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>0x234512 <element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>0x52341<element2><sub>3</sub></element2> <element2><sub>4</sub></element2>0x4312";

XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
xrs.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
XElement root = doc.Descendants().First();

using(var ms = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
{
    ms.Write(data);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(ms.BaseStream))
    //using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader("file.xml"))
    {
        using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(fs, xrs))
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    root.Add(XElement.Load(rdr.ReadSubtree()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you could also read directly from the file with another StreamReader constructor (remove the StreamWriter part)

Comment: check my edit --> using no regex should be faster and wont replace the content within the elementx's

Comment: following exception: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.

Comment: you have to remove the white space before the "<?xml" otherwise its not valid xml. if you have it anyway in the file you have to remove it first...

Comment: i think the error is because it's `<root><?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>` instead of `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>` - removing the first space doesn't help

Comment: use the second example individually --> dont use the code from before the edit. (only the first line for example data creation) --> i edited the code, now it should work

Comment: if you take all code now and execute it, it does not work? or it does not work with the file?

Comment: doesn't work both. can you verify this? i n some cases the file has `0x52341\n0x52341` at the beginning (see updated question) that seems to be the error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a console app that will do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = "0x52341<element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>0x234512 <element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>0x52341<element2><sub>3</sub></element2> <element2><sub>4</sub></element2>0x4312";
        List<string> components = new List<string>();
        while (source.Length > 0)
        {
            int start = source.IndexOf('<');
            if (-1 == start)
                break;
            int next = source.IndexOf("0x", start, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (-1 == next)
                break;
            components.Add(source.Substring(start, next - start));
            source = source.Substring(next);
        }
        foreach (string s in components)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Try that out.

Comment: that doesn't work because i also have `0x` values within my `<elementx>`

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't see that case in the example data. I just realized I also do not handle the case where you are leading one of the components with a space instead of a hex value. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: i simplified my file because i couldn't post the whole 10MB file in SO - sometimes there are `0x1234` values sometimes not, so i can't rely on them

Answer (score 0):

This processes the file as stream - looks for opening and closing element, parsing only those elements in process:

```
  using (var stream = File.OpenRead("..."))
  {
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    StringBuilder xml = null;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      {
        char c = (char)reader.Read();
        if (c == '<' && builder == null)
        {
          builder = new StringBuilder();
        }
        if (builder != null)
        {
          builder.Append(c);
        }
        if (xml != null)
        {
          xml.Append(c);
        }

        if (c == '>')
        {
          var token = builder.ToString();
          if (xml == null)
          {
            if (token.StartsWith("<element1", StringComparison.Ordinal) || token.StartsWith("<element2", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
              xml = new StringBuilder("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>");
              xml.Append(token);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if (token.StartsWith("</element1", StringComparison.Ordinal) || token.StartsWith("</element2", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
              XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml.ToString());
              // do something with the element
              xml = null;
            }
          }
          builder = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```